# Understanding Google DataTable prefixes

Tags: javascript, google-datatable

Google DataTable has this string as schema and data values:

```
{ 
cols: [{id: 'task',  label: 'Task',          type: 'string'}, 
      {id: 'hours', label: 'Hours per Day', type: 'number'}], 
rows: [{c:[{v: 'Work'},     {v: 11}]}, 
      {c:[{v: 'Eat'},      {v: 2}]}, 
      {c:[{v: 'Commute'},  {v: 2}]}, 
      {c:[{v: 'Watch TV'}, {v:2}]}, 
      {c:[{v: 'Sleep'},    {v:7, f:'7.000'}]} 
     ] 
}
```

What is v, f, c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#DataTable), where, as it seems, you got the example from, links to a description of the structure:

> **`opt_data`**
>   [*Optional*] Data used to initialize the table. This can either be the JSON returned by calling `DataTable.toJSON()` on a populated table, or a JavaScript object containing data used to initialize the table. **The structure of the JavaScript literal object is described [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#dataparam)**. If this parameter is not supplied, a new, empty data table will be returned.

Which leads to:

> `rows` Property
>
> The `rows` property holds an array of row objects.
>   Each row object has one required property called `c`, which is an array of cells in that row. It also has an optional `p` property that defines a map of arbitrary custom values to assign to the whole row. If your visualization supports any row-level properties it will describe them; otherwise, this property will be ignored.
>
> Cell Objects
>
> Each cell in the table is described by an object with the following properties:
>
> - `v` [*Optional*] The cell value. The data type should match the column data type. If null, the whole object should be empty and have neither `v` nor `f` properties.
> - `f` [*Optional*] A string version of the `v` value, formatted for display. The values should match, so if you specify `Date(2008, 0, 1)` for `v`, you should specify "January 1, 2008" or some such string for this property. This value is not checked against the `v` value. The visualization will not use this value for calculation, only as a label for display. If omitted, a string version of `v` will be used.
> - `p` [*Optional*] An object that is a map of custom values applied to the cell. These values can be of any JavaScript type. If your visualization supports any cell-level properties, it will describe them; otherwise, this property will be ignored. **Example:** `p:{style: 'border: 1px solid green;'}`.